# Create a new csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python and am trying to create a new csv file using the csv module (i.e. one that doesn't currently exist). Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: You should add more details as - how th data you want to write to the CSV file is represented in your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want simply create a csv file you can use built in method open, for more about open check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

```
with open("filename.csv","a+") as f:
     f.write(...)
```

or if you want to read an exist csv file you can use this

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in 
         print ', '.join(row)

#if you want to save the file into given path
import os
os.rename("filename.csv","path/to/new/desination/for/filename.csv")
```

for more check [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: If you use "rb" python will try opening the file for reading, and will raise an error, since the file does not exist.

Comment: Moreover, in Python3, the CSV module properly handles text, and there is no need for the "b" sufix.

Comment: yes that's why i said read file .. that means it exists to escape this you can see my answer above i will edit it

Comment: check my answer i edit it ,,,

Comment: Thank you but how do you then save the new file to a path?

Comment: @MKaye please check my edited answer .. :D

Comment: if i helped you .. please mark my answer as the best answer for your question, cheers.